# PySpark Data Frame, Convert Full Month Name to Int and then concat with year column and Day number to make a date

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am working with pyspark.  I have a pyspark dataframe with a Year Column and a Month Column where the month is fully spelled out

Ex:

| Year | Month |
| --- | --- |
| 2022 | January |
| 2021 | December |

I want to make 2 new date column (StartofMonth and EndofMonth)  In order to do so I need
a) Convert January to a integer, how do I do that?
b) I need to concatenate it to the Year and the number 1 to generate a "Start Month" Column eg: 2022-01-01
c) I need to concatenate Year and Integer version of month last day number for that month. eg: 2022-01-31

Is there a way I can do this with a function like unix time stamp and/or from unix time or some other functionality?

```
sourceDF.withColumn("mnth_num",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("Month"),'%B'),'MM')).show()
```

I have tried to the above for converting the month to an integer but that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of `pyspark.sql.functions` that can get you there! A possibility is the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_unixtime, unix_timestamp, col, concat_ws, lit, last_day

df = spark.createDataFrame([("2022", "January"), ("2021", "December")], ["Year", "Month"])

df2 = df.withColumn("month_name",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("Month"),'MMMM'),'MM')) \
        .withColumn("start_date", concat_ws("-", col("Year"), col("month_name"), lit("01"))) \
        .withColumn("end_date", last_day(col("start_date")))

df2.show()
+----+--------+----------+----------+----------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
|Year|   Month|month_name|start_date|  end_date|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
+----+--------+----------+----------+----------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
|2022| January|        01|2022-01-01|2022-01-31|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
|2021|December|        12|2021-12-01|2021-12-31|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
+----+--------+----------+----------+----------+
```

So we used:

- `from_unixtime` and `unix_timestamp` to manipulate the date into an integer format
- `concat_ws` and `lit` to concatenate the string columns against eachother (and adding a `lit` literal `"01"` string for the day
- `last_day` to calculate the last day in the month of our `start_date`

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a much clearer approach than mine. Didn't know that the functionality to get the month names exists, cool! Every day I learn something new :)

Comment: Ahhh yes I've had this happen multiple times as well, so great when you learn from others! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:** You can use to_date to get the month from month name, and last_day to get the last day in the month:

```
result = df.withColumn("start_date", concat(col("year"), lit("-"), lpad(month(to_date(col("month"), "MMMM")), 2, "0"), lit("-01"))) \
    .withColumn("end_of_month", last_day(col("start_date")))
```

**Solution 2:** You can create a dataframe containing all months with their respective order, join it to your dataframe, then use last_day function in spark to get the last day:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

data = [
    ["2022", "January"],
    ["2021", "December"],
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF("year", "month")

months_data = [["january", "01"], ["february", "02"], ["march", "03"], ["april", "04"], ["may", "05"],
               ["june", "06"], ["july", "07"], ["august", "08"], ["september", "09"], ["october", "10"],
               ["november", "11"], ["december", "12"]]
monthsDf = spark.createDataFrame(months_data).toDF("month_lib", "month_number")

result = df.join(monthsDf, lower(df.month) == lower(monthsDf.month_lib), "left") \
    .withColumn("start_date", concat(col("year"), lit("-"), col("month_number"), lit("-01"))) \
    .withColumn("end_of_month", last_day(col("start_date"))).select("year", "month", "start_date", "end_of_month")

result.show()
```

Comment: this seems to be working but there is one issue.  It is dropping columns from my original dataframe that is joing to the monthsDF.   I read a delta file in for the original data frame.   Any idea why it would drop the columns from the original frame?  the result.show() only has the columns year|month|start_date|end_of_month .  Is the because they are two different data frame types?

Comment: @user20634467 which solution did you use solution 1 or solution 2 ? I would prefer to use solution 1 because it's simpler.

Comment: I did solution #1 but ran into the issue where all the columns on the left side of the join went away except for month...

Comment: Actually with solution 1 there's no joins ? did you mean solution 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any native Pyspark functionality that would allow that, but you can create a mapping for it. Also, if you are only going to use it for concatenation to the year and day, you don't need an integer. You can do something like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, concat, col

df = df.withColumn(
    "MonthValue",
    when(col("Month") == "January", "01")
    .when(col("Month") == "February", "02")
    .when(col("Month") == "March", "03")
    .when(col("Month") == "April", "04")
    .when(col("Month") == "May", "05")
    .when(col("Month") == "June", "06")
    .when(col("Month") == "July", "07")
    .when(col("Month") == "August", "08")
    .when(col("Month") == "September", "09")
    .when(col("Month") == "October", "10")
    .when(col("Month") == "November", "11")
    .when(col("Month") == "December", "12")
    .otherwise(None)
)
```

Then you can concatenate it like this:

```
df = df.withColumn(
    "YearMonth",
    concat(col("Year"), "-", col("MonthValue"))
)
```